# Replacing project dependency with a versioned artifact in the uploadArchives task

Tags: android, gradle, pom.xml, gradle-dependencies

I have a setup, libA, and libB, libB is a dependency of libA.

While using Gradle...

Once uploadArchives task is executed, both archives will be built. Each project is versioned, and the version can be retrieved from the subproject folder.

What I would like to do is set the version of libB in the pom.xml of libA before it is signed and uploaded to the repo.

How can I get the project dependencies for pure Java and Android project in the uploadArchive task?

How do I change it's version?

Answer (score 0):

So.... this was unexpected!

Apparently you need to make sure that each of your subprojects have their own version project.version, and the uploadArchives tasks resolves it by itself.